# jira-python - how do you update the fixVersions field?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, and am hoping someone else has the same problem. I don't get any error, and my json matches what should be correct both on Jira's docs and jira-python questions online. My versions are valid Jira versions. I also have no problem doing this directly through the API, but we are re-writing everything to go through jira-python for cleanliness/ease of use.

This just completely clears the fixVersions field in Jira.

```
issue=jira.issue("TKT-100")
issue.update(fields={'fixVersions':[{'add': {'name': 'add_me'}},{'remove': {'name': 'remove_me'}}]})
```

I can add a new version to fixVersions using issue.add_field_value(), but this won't work, because I need to add and remove in one request for the history of the ticket.

```
issue.add_field_value('fixVersions', {'name': 'add_me'})
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I actually figured out that you can do this by first finding all fixVersions in a ticket, throwing all but the one you want to remove into a list, append your new fixVersion, and use the 'set' verb instead of 'add' and 'remove'. Jira doesn't overwrite the other fixVersion values.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's a code example of how I got it working for anyone who comes across this later...

```
    fixVersions = []
    issue = jira.issue('issue_key')
    for version in issue.fields.fixVersions:
        if version.name != 'version_to_remove':
            fixVersions.append({'name': version.name})
    fixVersions.append({'name': 'version_to_add'})
    issue.update(fields={'fixVersions': fixVersions})
```

Comment: I actually started with this approach and noticed it was clearing out the existing versions. Only the last version stuck. But using add_field_value() did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

I did it other way:

1. Create version in the target project.
2. Update ticket.

   ver = jira.create_version(name='version_name', project='PROJECT_NAME')
   issue = jira.issue('ISSUE_NUM')
   i.update(fields={'fixVersions': [{'name': ver.name}]})}

In my case that worked.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit more pythonic version of user797963 solution, may look like that.

```
def change_fix_version(tickets, remove_versions=[], add_versions=[]):
    fix_versions={version.name for version in ticket.fields.fixVersions}
    fix_versions.difference_update(set(remove_versions))
    fix_versions.update(set(add_versions))
    ticket.update(fields={'fixVersions':fix_versions})
```

You would call it like that:

```
 change_fix_versions(jira.issue('my_issue'), remove_versions=['draft'], add_versions=['master', 'release'])
```

Comment: you forgot that fix_versions should be a list of dicts. `fix_versions=[version.raw for version in ticket.fields.fixVersions]`. and then you should assume your usage is like this `change_fix_versions(jira.issue('my_issue'), remove_versions=[{'name':'draft'}], add_versions=[{'name':'master'}, {'name':'release'}])'`